# better way of solving the url issue

Tags: django

So i followed the poll example from django documentation. 
can anyone please help out for solving this problem.

```
url(r'^polls/test1/$', 'polls.views.test1'),
url(r'^polls/test/$', 'polls.views.test2'),



def test1(request):
   latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('polls/test1.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list})

def test2(request):
    latest_poll_list = some_var_from_template['poll_list']
    return render_to_response('polls/test2.html', {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list})

<a href = "{% url polls.view.test2 %}{{latest_poll_list.count}} </a>
```

So basically I just want to show number of polls objects in poll/test1/  template and a link to next url to poll/test2/

In poll/test2/ template i just want the same latest_poll_list object. 
so i can say `<a href = "{% url polls.view.test2 latest_poll_list %}{{latest_poll_list.count}} </a>`   but the problem is it takes the latest_poll_list in the argument of test2 view function, which i don't want as my polls list can have 1m records. and the url will become very long.

Is there any other way i can solve this problem or my approach to solve this problem is totally wrong?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're trying to do. What is the point of `latest_poll_list`? What are you trying to pass to the second view? What are you trying to show in that second view?

Comment: I have read your question twice, but still can't unserstand what you're trying to achieve. What should be in test2 url?

Comment: I'm confused by this question - Neither your view nor your URL takes any parameters. Attempting to do what you are doing would not even match your urls.

Comment: hey, the thing is I just want to show only the number of Poll count in the first url, so when user click on the count he get redirected to 2 url which show the details of poll list. so say i have 10 models. i just want to show the number of record for each model on first url and when user click on the count he gets redirected to 2 url with the object. so that i can write one url and 1 view for each of the model. I hope i made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no user interaction in *test1.html* that may influence the selection process in the *test2* view, there is no reason to pass anything at all. Simply leave out the argument `latest_poll_list` in the `{% url %}` tag, and select the poll list in test2 in the same way you do in test1.

Comment: so say i have 10 models and i am  displaying the number of records for each model on the first url. so when the user click on the link count he get redirected to 2 url which display the details of each model.

Comment: You say "the number of records for each model". Does that mean you have more models than just the model Poll? (Such as another model DisussionThread, BlogEntry or whatever is applicable to your site) and want to link to lists of all objects for each of these models --- Or do you mean that on the overview page you want a list of all Poll _objects_ in your database? If that is the case, what do you want to display on the detail page for a particular Poll object? Do you have a model PollAnswer or something similar, and a way to represent the number of times each answer was picked?